# Java Process.waitFor() and IO streams

Tags: java, runtime, subprocess, stdio

I have the following code;

```
String[] cmd = { "bash", "-c", "~/path/to/script.sh" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

PipeThread a = new PipeThread(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
PipeThread b = new PipeThread(p.getErrorStream(), System.err);

p.waitFor();

a.die();
b.die();
```

The `PipeThread` class is quite simple so I will include it in full;

```
public class PipeThread implements Runnable {

    private BufferedInputStream in;
    private BufferedOutputStream out;

    public Thread thread;

    private boolean die = false;

    public PipeThread(InputStream i, OutputStream o) {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(i);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(o);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void die() { die = true; }

    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            while(!die) {
                int x = in.read(b, 0, 1024);
                if(x > 0) out.write(b, 0, x);
                else die();
                out.flush();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        try { 
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

My problem is this; `p.waitFor()` blocks endlessly, even after the subprocess has terminated. If I *do not* create the pair of `PipeThread` instances, then `p.waitFor()` works perfectly. What is it about the piping of io streams that is causing `p.waitFor()` to continue blocking?

I'm confused as I thought the IO streams would be passive, unable to keep a process alive, or to make Java think the process is still alive.

Comment: Did you `start()` your threads? In the code you pasted here, you did not.

Comment: @infgeoax the `start()` is called in the constructor. It might be poor practise, but it's there :)

Comment: Try `private volatile boolean die`?

Comment: Oh wow, I just realised what is going on...it's funny enough that I will answer my own question. Hopefully someone will laugh with me...

Comment: When read() returns -1, it isn't in general adequate just to call a method. You should break out of the loop and close the stream. There is also little point in using a BufferedOutputStream *and* flushing inside the loop.

Comment: @EJP the -1 will immediately cause a `flush()` followed by a `close()` does this not look ok to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much head-scratching, I realised what is happening. `p.waitFor()` actually *isn't* blocking indefinitely, rather my method of checking it is failing; a `System.out.println()` statement after `p.waitFor()`.

`PipeThread` is a class that I had lying around from a previous project, and I have often used it to pipe one stream onto another in a separate thread.

This must be the first time I have used it with `System.out`. `PipeThread` closes whatever streams it is passed upon reading `EOF`. Both streams in this case included my standard output, so debugging with `System.out.println` becomes impossible... :(

Weirdly, no `IOException` was thrown by `System.out.println()`, I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

In your `PipeThread` code you are looping forever until !die - but you call `PipeThread.die()` after `p.waitFor()` - what's exactly stopping the `PipeThread` threads?

Comment: In the `PipeThread.run()` you will see the line `else die();` which will kill the thread (and close the streams) upon reading `EOF`

Comment: Don't think that's the problem - but die should be declared volatile as it is accessed by multiple threads. Are you sure that thread terminates properly (can you put a println right after the end of the while)

Comment: I have checked the termination of the `PipeThreads` and they are working correctly. See my answer for the cause of the confusion. Also thanks for the tip about `volatile`, I forget it so often.